# Testing Java with NetBeans

Tags: java, unit-testing, netbeans

I have a project named JavaProject2 which contains one package named `some.myPackage`. That package contains three .java files. Now I want to add a .java file (ie Mytest.java) that does testing with JUnit. 
Where should I put that file? I put it on the source files but there are no testing results. If I place it on a Test Package then I will not be able to use the public classes and functions I have made in the other files. 
In the beginning of the source file it has `package some.myPackage;`. Whenever I run test it always gives me an error.

ERROR 
`Unknown caused an error (0.0 s)`

It displays the same error whether I have or not the Mytest.java file is present.

Can anyone help me resolve this error? Please don't give me a downvote, I have been trying to figure this out for the last 4 hours.

Can I remain having one and only source package? Or have I got to make an additional test package?

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Did the project successfully compile *before* you added the test class?

Comment: @Leigh The IDE runs successfully the code. The GUI program appears correctly. The problem is that I can not test the program. How can I import a testing file that has in the first line the `package Mypackage` ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'testing file'? If you want to use JUnit you must create a Java class.

Comment: @home I have a homework to do. And the first part is to make a GUI . The second part is to test it with a certain file. Where should I put that file in my project?

Comment: And what do you want this file to do? Is it just a text file or a Java class? You must work on your question...

Comment: @home The file has a Java class and tests with the help of the JUnit.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this tutorial: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/junit-intro.html

In general you have in Netbeans under "Source Packages" your program and under "Test Packages" your unit tests. You should use the same package-structure for both of them.
E.g. if you have under "Source Packages" "some.myPackage.MainProgram" you should have under "Test Packages" "some.myPackage.MainProgramTest". Even though those classes are organized in different directories on your harddisk they remain in the same package and from a Java point-of-view they are in the same location (/package). Does this help?